# How can I add items in listWidget?

Tags: python, python-2.7, python-3.x, qt-creator

I have trouble adding item in listWidget

I made UI with QT creator and want to import it in python.

When I run this code the items doesn't shows in listWidget, only white blanks.

what is the problem??

please help me

my code is

```
import sys
from PyQt4 import QtCore, QtGui
from secdialog import Ui_SecDialog

class SecDialog(QtGui.QDialog, Ui_SecDialog):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        QDialog.__init__(self, parent)
        self.setupUi(self)
        self.listWidget.addItem("QlistItem_1");
        self.listWidget.addItem("QlistItem_2");
        self.listWidget.addItem("QlistItem_3");


if __name__ == '__main__': 
    app = QtGui.QApplication(sys.argv)
    ex = Ui_SecDialog()        
    ex.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Comment: You create an instance of `Ui_SecDialog` in `ex` but I think you want to create a `SecDialog` instance

Comment: Oh, I made a stupid mistake! THANKS :)

Answer (score 0):

You create an instance of `Ui_SecDialog` in `ex` but you want to create a `SecDialog` instance:

`ex = SecDialog()`